# $log = LogFile->new($cfg{logdir} . '/tpchc.log', ($tpchc->{args}->{debug}) ? 1 : 0) what does this mean please explain

Tags: perl

$log = LogFile->new($cfg{logdir} . '/tpchc.log', ($tpchc->{args}->{debug}) ? 1 : 0)

Can someone please tell me what this means

Comment: The constructor LogFile->new() returns LogFile object $log

Answer (score 1):

The code is creating a new `LogFile` object, which takes two arguments: the path to the log file and a debug boolean flag.

In this case the first argument is using concatenation (with the period) and the second argument is being set using a [ternary if-else](https://perlmaven.com/the-ternary-operator-in-perl).

Perl is a compile-at-run-time language so it allows you to write arguments directly in a constructor this way (though there are limits to this). It's the same as doing:

```
my $file  = $cfg{logdir} . '/tpchc.log';
my $debug = $tpchc->{args}->{debug} ? 1 : 0;
my $log   = LogFile->new($file, $debug);
```

Incidentally, simple hashes and hashrefs (but not objects) can be interpolated in a string, so you don't actually need to concatenate the `$file` line:

```
my $file = "$cfg{logdir}/tpchc.log";
```

Some people find that easier to read and some don't so to each their own.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer , but can you let me know how this statement works, $tpchc->{args}->{debug} , i mean why is it referencing twice ? please help

Comment: @amith cm, It's a complex hash. `$tpchc` is a hashref and the value assigned to `args` is also a hashref. `debug` is one of the keys inside of the `args` hashref. The full `$tpchc->{args}->{debug}` returns the value of the `debug` key. The [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) perldocs  can give you more information about how hashrefs work.